# Understanding a dmesg kernel warning message

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-panic, dmesg

I am trying to debug my kernel module.
When I run it I get the following kernel warnings, but it seems that there is no informative message like other warnings I've seen. Is it possible to get any useful info out of this?

---

Some more info:

The module is called `firewall`, it diverts tcp packets to a proxy server in user space, and the proxy then sends the tcp data it receives to the intended destination.

This happens when processing an http response by simply receiving all the data on one socket and calling sendall on another.
The warning doesn't happen when all the response comes in one packet, but does when the http payload data is segmented into several tcp packets.

The proxy is written in python. It seems strange to me that in the warning it says "python tainted". Can userspace applications cause kernel warnings?

---

I tried only receiving a large file in the proxy but not sending it and did not get any errors, and the system didn't freeze at any point. The problem happens only on calling socket.sendall/socket.send

reducing the read buffer size and then sending smaller chunks causes the system to lockup faster.

Turning off both `gso`, `tso` with `ethtool` prevents the error messages, but the system still locks up after the same amount of time, making me wonder if the warnings are even tied to the lockup

```
[16795.153478] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[16795.153489] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-3.2.0/net/core/dev.c:1970 skb_gso_segment+0x2e9/0x360()
[16795.153492] Hardware name: VirtualBox
[16795.153495] e1000: caps=(0x40014b89, 0x401b4b89) len=2948 data_len=0 ip_summed=0
[16795.153497] Modules linked in: firewall(O) vesafb vboxsf(O) snd_intel8x0 snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device joydev psmouse snd soundcore serio_raw i2c_piix4 snd_page_alloc vboxguest(O) video bnep mac_hid rfcomm bluetooth parport_pc ppdev lp parport usbhid hid e1000 [last unloaded: firewall]
[16795.153529] Pid: 7644, comm: python Tainted: G        W  O 3.2.0-37-generic-pae #58-Ubuntu
[16795.153532] Call Trace:
[16795.153540]  [<c105a822>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
[16795.153544]  [<c14ad2b9>] ? skb_gso_segment+0x2e9/0x360
[16795.153548]  [<c14ad2b9>] ? skb_gso_segment+0x2e9/0x360
[16795.153551]  [<c105a8f3>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
[16795.153555]  [<c14ad2b9>] skb_gso_segment+0x2e9/0x360
[16795.153561]  [<c14b01ce>] dev_hard_start_xmit+0xae/0x4c0
[16795.153568]  [<f9a6f2fd>] ? divertPacket+0x7d/0xe0 [firewall]
[16795.153574]  [<c14c8151>] sch_direct_xmit+0xb1/0x180
[16795.153578]  [<f9a6f941>] ? hook_localout+0x71/0xe0 [firewall]
[16795.153582]  [<c14b06d6>] dev_queue_xmit+0xf6/0x370
[16795.153586]  [<c14c6459>] ? eth_header+0x29/0xc0
[16795.153590]  [<c14b73f0>] neigh_resolve_output+0x100/0x1c0
[16795.153594]  [<c14c6430>] ? eth_rebuild_header+0x80/0x80
[16795.153598]  [<c14dec62>] ip_finish_output+0x152/0x2e0
[16795.153602]  [<c14df75f>] ip_output+0xaf/0xc0
[16795.153605]  [<c14dd340>] ? ip_forward_options+0x1d0/0x1d0
[16795.153609]  [<c14deec0>] ip_local_out+0x20/0x30
[16795.153612]  [<c14defee>] ip_queue_xmit+0x11e/0x3c0
[16795.153617]  [<c10841c5>] ? getnstimeofday+0x55/0x120
[16795.153622]  [<c14f4de7>] tcp_transmit_skb+0x2d7/0x4a0
[16795.153626]  [<c14f5786>] tcp_write_xmit+0x146/0x3a0
[16795.153630]  [<c14f5a4c>] __tcp_push_pending_frames+0x2c/0x90
[16795.153634]  [<c14e7d2b>] tcp_sendmsg+0x71b/0xae0
[16795.153638]  [<c104a33d>] ? update_curr+0x1ed/0x360
[16795.153642]  [<c1509c23>] ? inet_recvmsg+0x73/0x90
[16795.153646]  [<c1509ca0>] inet_sendmsg+0x60/0xa0
[16795.153650]  [<c149ae27>] sock_sendmsg+0xf7/0x120
[16795.153655]  [<c1044648>] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x28/0x130
[16795.153660]  [<c1036a98>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x8/0x10
[16795.153667]  [<c149ce7e>] sys_sendto+0x10e/0x150
[16795.153672]  [<c1117e7f>] ? handle_pte_fault+0x28f/0x2c0
[16795.153675]  [<c111809e>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x15e/0x2c0
[16795.153679]  [<c15ab9c7>] ? do_page_fault+0x227/0x490
[16795.153681]  [<c149cefb>] sys_send+0x3b/0x40
[16795.153684]  [<c149d842>] sys_socketcall+0x162/0x2c0
[16795.153687]  [<c15af55f>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[16795.153689] ---[ end trace 3170256120cbbc8f ]---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried following backwards from end of stack trace with `addr2line`?

For example looking at the last line `sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28`

It tells us that the offset is `0x12` and the length is `0x28`

`$ addr2line -e [path-to-kernel-module-with-issue] 0xc15af55f`

and so on...`gdb` is another alternative in terms of breaking down the stack trace into lines.

However, I am not completely sure how you are arriving at a kernel-panic, as all I am seeing in the log excerpt you provided is a warning. Does it result in a crash/kernel-panic message after the stack-trace you posted?

-------as far as the stack trace posted: it has to do with the general segmentation offload and the skbuffer not being happy with the ip_summed checksum, disabling large\general receiver offload with

`$ethtool -k [NIC] lro off`
`$ethtool -k [NIC] gro off`

might be a possible workaround. Also, skipping checksum check with `skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_UNNECESSARY` might also solve this issue, depending on the purpose of the setup.

Comment: Sorry, the tag is misleading, it doesn't cause a kernel panic in dmesg but if I run the program enough times or on a large enough file (try to transfer a large enough file) the system locks up. It seems that there is a warning for every packet with http data. Is it possible that the kernel runs out of memory because my program floods dmesg?

Comment: No! After reexamining the stacktrace more closely, what causes this is warning if I am not mistaken is your general segmentation offload(gso) sk buffer is not satisfied with the ip_summed checksum and will kick off this warning. You should try turning off large receiver offload or generic receiver offload with `ethtool -k [your NIC device, ethX etc.] lro off` or `ethtool -k gro off` .

Comment: I edit the skb of packets that enter/leave my firewall and then fix their checksum in divert_packet. Is it possible that for segmented data something gets messed up there?

Comment: I tried only receiving a large file in the proxy but not sending it and did not get any errors. Seems the problem is sending the data. Tried turning off `tso` but did not help

Comment: Turning both gso, tso off stops the warnings but it still locks up after sending a few large files

Comment: How large of a file are we talking about?

Comment: Also, given that e1000 is a virtual dev for a 1Gb NIC in vbox, 1. Have you tried using another virtual adapter driver available through virtual box, and if so did this problem  occur in the same way regardless of adapter type selected ? 2. are you seeing messages related to repeated disconnects or adapter resets in either the host or your vm when in use. You might see things like `transmit timed out; status 0073, resetting`.

Comment: It seems that the size of an individual file matters less. What does matter is the total amount of data I transmit. After a bit of debugging it seems that it happens only when I send data. Also, the warnings happen when I call `skb_linearize` on nonlinear `skb` and then send. I think this is more of a question for stackoverflow on my checksum computing function.

Comment: Ok so the size has nothing to do with it and what crashed my system was incorrect use of spinlocks. These warnings have nothing to do with the crashes.